# Sine law and circumscribed circle

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

[image]

How is $\frac{a}{\sin(A)}=2R$ (where $R$ is the radius) derived?

Comment: draw a stright line through $a$ and $D$ and intersect this with the given circle, then you will get a right angled triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I trust you know that $\angle BDC=2 \angle A $

Construct an isosceles $\triangle  BDC $.

Drop perpendicular from D to BC.

See that $a=2R \cdot \sin (\frac {1}{2} \angle BDC) $

Substitute the first equality I mentioned

Comment: Very nicely shown. +1

Comment: @Joanpemo thankyou